# Get all users with properties from Azure AD with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to get all users from my **Azure AD** using `C#`and send them with all their properties to other **AD**. I'm already get all users(with graph API), but i cant find how to take all of their properties (with or without Graph API). I cant find examples or something.

So question is, how to take all users and all of their props (even if they are empty)?

Comment: So, like, umm, what else do you need that `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` doesn't give you?

Comment: Yes it gives, but how to use it in my C# code unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: @evilSnobu Can you give me an example of using it in C# code (to use it in a web app)?

Comment: You leave a lot of guesswork for us, the folks trying to help. Try to ask a better question or better yet read through the samples - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/aspnetmvc

Comment: What additional info you need to help me with this problem?

Comment: @evilSnobu can you show me how to get users with props or show some example?